# SQL Table sorting by multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table i need to sort but im not certain on what the right ORDER BY statement would be. Here is an example:

we need to sort by ASCENDING Name, then DESCENDING Values, then ASCENDING Location. But if rows have the same Name and Location then we sort by ASCENDING Values.

BEFORE SORTING:

| Name | Location | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | T | 1000 |
| A | U | 2000 |
| A | V | 2500 |
| B | X | 3000 |
| B | Y | 4000 |
| C | X | 1000 |
| C | T | 500 |
| C | U | 1000 |
| C | V | 6000 |
| D | Z | 9000 |
| D | Z | 7000 |
| D | X | 300 |

AFTER SORTING:

| Name | Location | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | V | 2500 |
| A | U | 2000 |
| A | T | 1000 |
| B | Y | 4000 |
| B | X | 3000 |
| C | V | 6000 |
| C | U | 1000 |
| C | X | 1000 |
| C | T | 500 |
| D | Z | 7000 |
| D | Z | 9000 |
| D | X | 300 |

Sorry its a bit lengthy! but all situations are described in the tables above!

Comment: *Almost* all situations covered. If D|Z|7000 were D|Z|100 instead, would you show D|Z first, because 9000 > 300 or D|X first, because 300 > 100?

Answer (score 1):

Using  a window function to get a sort key for a group

```
select *
from (
  select *, min(Values) over(partition by Name, Location) gmin
  from t
) t
order by Name, gmin desc, Location, values
```

Comment: Good answer. The OP may want `MAX OVER` instead of `MIN OVER` depending on how the OP wants to deal with a group having both lesser and greater values as another. The subquery is not necessary; the window function can just as well be applied in the order by clause directly.